# How does Github know which user made the commit?

Tags: ubuntu, php, ssh, git, gitolite

I am trying to write a little GUI for my gitolite server. My plan is to create a hook, which then writes the `git log` to a database or a file. Then a php file can read this data and display it like the network on github.

My problem is now how do I know which user has made the commit? Because if his git email is different then the email in my servers database I have no way to identify the user.

Do you have any suggestions for this problem?

Is there a better way to get all commits than `git log`?

Comment: The short answer is that Github _doesn't_ know who made the commit unless that person's email addresses are registered in their profile. They have the same issue you have, and they haven't solved it.

Comment: The only real way around this would be to require signing of every commit, and rejecting commits that are signed by keys you don't recognize. Then you can tie the key to the user instead of the email address provided in the commit itself.